# 14.04 stuck in login loop when watching Youtube

Tags: 14.04, login, youtube

I've had a look at a few other login loop questions and they all seem to include an nVidia graphics card.  I have an intel graphics card so I don't think that's my issue.

I get stuck in a login loop and have to restart to get out of it whenever I watch a youtube video, either embedded or on youtube.com. I'm using the latest stable Google Chrome browser.

How do I fix this issue?

**Update to the problem**

Not only affects Youtube, but Netflix as well. The System Crash Report reads as follows:

```
ExecutablePath
/usr/sbin/unity-greeter

Problem Type
Crash

Architecture
i386
```

Comment: Does it happen to other browsers too? For example Firefox etc...

Comment: Just checked and no, Firefox seems to work okay, which leads me to believe it's in Chrome.

I installed with:
    cd /tmp
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
    sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb

Comment: well if this works with Firefox then it's hardly related to Ubuntu I'd say but mostly to Google Chrome issue/bug. You can also contact Google Chrome support [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome) or report it to [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/). There's also an open-source that you can use in Linux/Ubuntu the Chromium browser which is original source for Google Chrome and others alike. You can install it with: `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer if anyone else stumbles upon this.

- First, go in to the settings for Google Chrome
- Scroll down and click on "Show Advanced Settings"
- Scroll down some more to "System"
- It should have two boxes checked off, you need to uncheck the box labled **Use hardware acceleration when available**

This should solve the problem as it has for me.